# Logs not visible in datadog even after submit_logs returns {}

Tags: aws-lambda, datadog

I am currently using Send logs(https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs/?code-lang=python#send-logs) method to push the logs from lambda to datadog. I am sending a dummy
message for testing purposes. I am forwarding the following body to datadog:

```
body = HTTPLog(
        [
            HTTPLogItem(
                ddsource="test-sp-api",
                ddtags="SP-API-TEST",
                hostname="TEST-Host",
                message="NN",
                service="first-service",
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Below is the response of the submit_log function:
[image]

I am expecting the logs to be visible in datadog. I haven't defined any body parameters in datadog. Am I missing something here? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code? There's something strange in your output - it says about failure, then about success.

Comment: @michail_w:  Please ignore the second line as I am printing some results set(JSON). I am not passing it in the body. The function returns an empty response which means that it succeeded.

Comment: @michail_w: The screenshot has been updated

Comment: Are you hitting the limits? The docs of the send-logs function say about such limits:

- Maximum content size per payload (uncompressed): 5MB
- Maximum size for a single log: 1MB
- Maximum array size if sending multiple logs in an array: 1000 entries

Comment: @michail_w: I am only sending the body shared in the description.

Comment: @michail_w: I have only set up an API key in the datadog env.  Do we need to add any variable/sources/services as well? As per my understanding, these logs should be processed

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem (but with Typescript).  For me the solution was to include a timestamp in the message.

For example:

```
2022-09-14T22:08:21.038Z {"event":"deployment"}
```